# Json value not getting binded to kendo dropdown

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui

Im reading values from a javascript file. Im trying to bind a particular field into a kendo dropdown. i'm able to read the values but i could't assign them in the kendo dropdownlist.

```
var json = [
{
    "Type": "ABC",
    "Icon": "Ro.png"        
 }
},
{
    "Type": "DEF",
    "Icon": "Po.png",        
    }
}];
```

HTML :

```
   <select id="ListCurrencyDiv" class="testdiv"> </select>
```

Function:

```
  function BindValue() {
     $(".testdiv").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: function (BindValue) {
                operation.success(json);
            }
        }
    },
    dataTextField: "Type",
    dataValueField: "Type",
    value: "No notification"
});}BindValue();
```

Comment: Did yout tried this? `dataSource: json, ` ?

Comment: yes i tried that, but no help

Comment: Your `json` object is invalid. Copy it and paste on the console. You'll see an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, fix your `json` object:

```
var json = [
{
    "Type": "ABC",
    "Icon": "Ro.png"        
},
{
    "Type": "DEF",
    "Icon": "Po.png",  
}];
```

Now that it becomes valid, try reading it directly in the `dataSource` option:

```
dataSource: json,
```

If [this first demo from Kendo](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/index.html) and your code are right, it should work.

Comment: Thanks it worked.one more issue was i missed "kendo.all.min.js" this link